# DataTable.Rows.Find(MultiplePrimaryKey) In Powershell

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, powershell, datatable

I'm working with a SQL Server Table, I'm bringing over as a datatable make some modification and save the data back to the database.

I'm stuck right now on finding the correct syntax for the DataTable.Rows.Find(PrimaryKey)

For simplicity I create a simple datatable with some data 
you can test it on your end as well.

Here is my syntax.

```
[System.Data.DataTable]$dtGL = New-Object System.Data.DataTable("GL")
#Schemas
$dtGL.Columns.Add("Account", "String") | Out-Null
$dtGL.Columns.Add("Property", "String") | Out-Null
$dtGL.Columns.Add("Date", "DateTime") | Out-Null
$dtGL.Columns.Add("Amount", "Decimal") | Out-Null

[System.Data.DataColumn[]]$KeyColumn = ($dtGL.Columns["Account"],$dtGL.Columns["Property"],$dtGL.Columns["Date"])
$dtGL.PrimaryKey = $KeyColumn 

#Records
$dtGL.Rows.Add('00001','1000','1/1/2018','185') | Out-Null 
$dtGL.Rows.Add('00001','1000','1/2/2018','486') | Out-Null
$dtGL.Rows.Add('00001','1001','1/1/2018','694') | Out-Null
$dtGL.Rows.Add('00001', '1001', '1/2/2018', '259') | Out-Null

[String[]]$KeyToFind = '00001', '1001', '01/01/2018'
$FoundRows = $dtGL.Rows.Find($KeyToFind)
$FoundRows | Out-GridView
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Exception calling "Find" with "1" argument(s): "Expecting 3 value(s) for the key being indexed, but received 1 value(s)."
At C:\Users\MyUserName\OneDrive - MyUserName\MyCompany\PowerShell\Samples\Working With DataTable.ps1:32 char:5
+     $FoundRows = $dtGL.Rows.Find($KeyToFind)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

I also tried to separate the parameters

```
$P01 = '00001'
$P02 = '1001'
$P03 = '01/01/2018'

$FoundRows = $dtGL.Rows.Find($P01,$P02,$P03)
```

Here is the error

```
Cannot find an overload for "Find" and the argument count: "3".
+     $FoundRows = $dtGL.Rows.Find($P01,$P02,$P03)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: Does it work if you give the three args instead of wrapping them in an array?

Comment: No I just tried that

Comment: @Codernator You should edit your question with this additional information and the new exact error msg (no overload...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work well, i tried as follows:

```
$P01 = '00001'
$P02 = '1001'
$P03 = '01/01/2018'

$FoundRows = $dtGL.Rows.Find(@($P01,$P02,$P03))
```

Answer (score 4):

[DataRowCollection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6dh4x2h(v=vs.110).aspx) requires an object array.  Before your edit you showed you were passing in an array of strings.  This would work if every primary key column was of the String type.  Since you have a DateTime you need to pass an Object array and the value for the Date column should be of the DateTime type.

Try changing the way you implement your KeyToFind to be an object array, casting each different type along the way:

```
[Object[]]$KeyToFind = [String]'00001', [String]'1001', [DateTime]'01/01/2018'
```